# How to keep my essay from crossing the word limit?

Tags: creative-writing

I want to write an essay on pollution in not more than 150 words. But there are many different forms of pollution, and describing them separately is exceeding the word limit.

Please suggest me ways as to how to deal with the problem.

Comment: What tools are you using to write this (pen/pencil and paper?  Computer?).

Comment: Essay with "not more than 150 words"... may I ask you if you have a Twitter account? ;)

Comment: Including the header, this question contains 53 words. Bottom line is... you're seriously screwed.

Answer (score 2):

Write your thesis statement. What's the point you're making? Expand it, ignoring your word limit. Then tighten the text to fit your limit.

Here's how I tighten text:

- For every adverb and adjective, consider how a stronger verb or noun would allow you to delete the descriptive word.
- Are there sentences that can be combined to save words?
- Are there words or sentences that are redundant?
- Is your thesis or summary statements necessary anymore?